# html div overlay for a beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For each line of text I read in, I would like to make something like this:
`<div style id="overlayr3"> some-name </div>`

so that my example works like this one (http://jsfiddle.net/jsnga/) where the overlay is associated to the id number.

Here is the relevant bit of what I have so far: any help is much appreciated!

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "coords1.txt", true); 
xhr.onload = function(e) {
if(this.status == 200) {
    // get text contents

var coords = xhr.responseText.split("\n");
    coords = coords.filter(Boolean) //prevents extra rect with 0 coords
    coords.forEach(function(coord) {
            // create new area element 
            var area = document.createElement("area");
            area.id = "r3";

             //create overlay with first term in string
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id ="overlayr3"; 

            // get map element
            document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(area);
            document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div);
        });
}
};
```

From here, I do:

```
if($('#demo')) {
    $('#demo area').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $('#overlay'+id).show();
        });

        $(this).mouseout(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#overlay'+id).hide();
        });

    });
}


xhr.send();

});
```

I add here a manual example that works (without reading in from a text file):

```
<map name="demo" id="demo">
<area shape="rect" coords="794,359,905,318" href="#" id="r1" alt="r1">

</map>

<div style id="overlayr1"> cscCSL1A15 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


if($('#demo')) {
    $('#demo area').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $('#overlay'+id).show();
        });

        $(this).mouseout(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#overlay'+id).hide();
        });

    });
}
$('#overlayr1').hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Youre missing a } to close the foreach function

Comment: may be it's there and he did not included the entire code..

Comment: To make it easier for us to answer the question, please provide errors or a comparison of what you want and what happened

Comment: @jonju: i know. Thats why i commented and didnt put it as an answer

Comment: Thank you for your replies! What I am trying to replicate in the jsfiddle that I linked is this line: <div id="overlayr1">&nbsp;</div> I don't know how to add text like the "&nbsp" to the div element that I created, I have just defined the id. I am reading in a text file line by line, and I'd like to put a substring of each line here: 
<div id="overlayr1">my_substring</div>

Comment: div.innerHtml=yourstring;

Comment: @Jonas w thank you, I have added this. A problem is that I am assigning the id "r3" to each area element as I loop over the text file...is there a way that I could assign the id "rn" where n=1,2,3.. and then write div.id ="overlayrn"; ?

Comment: div.id="r3"+i;i++; set i=0 before the foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=0;
coords.forEach(function(coord) { 
 // create new area element
 var area =     document.createElement("area");
 area.id = "r"+i; 
 area.innerHtml=content;
 //increase i
 i++;

//create overlay with first term in string
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.id ="overlayr"+i; 
// get map element.    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(area);     document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(div); });
```

Comment: Thank you! A variation of this worked. My final problem is- at the end (see manual example I have put at the bottom of the problem statement) I would like to hide all of the overlays (all n of them) like: 
$('#overlayrn').hide(); How can I do this?

Comment: div.style.display="none";

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have any advice on how I should solve this related problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813350/beginner-modifying-mouseover-javascript